# Filling up the 3rd party website fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is the problem in my project, this is a function which a text "time in" was entered, the script will be executed and third party website will fill by the if block. If you want to me to give more details just tell me what specific detail you need, just comment below.

```
function MessageHandler(context, event) {
    //context.console.log("test")
    var x = event.message.toLowerCase();
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    if(hours > 11){
    z = "AM";
    } else {
    z = "PM";
    }
    w = (hours + 8 + ":" + minutes + " " + z);
  if(x.startsWith("time in")) {
        context.sendResponse("timed in at " + w);
        var desc = "BOT TIME IN";
        var proj = "Koodi - Training"; //just in case value doesn't work, try: var proj = 5;(this is for me)
        var tick = "15"; //put random number in testing.
        /*i want here the code that will make the data to be inserted in the fields of the 3rd party website(http://timebound.dev2.koodi.ph/timer)
        these are the fields of the 3rd party website which i want the date to be filled:

            <input placeholder="What are you working on?" id="timer-desc" tabindex="1" name="description" type="text">

            <select tabindex="-1" id="timer-project" name="project_id" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="5">Koodi - Training</option>
            <option value="19">Koodi Marketing</option>
            <option value="6">Koodi Site</option>
            <option value="2">Wisebread - D6</option>
            </select>

            <input placeholder="Ticket reference" tabindex="3" id="timer-ticket" name="ticket" type="text">

        Lastly, I want this button to be clicked(automatically of course) after the fields are filled.
        <input class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="timer-btn" type="submit" value="Start">
        */
    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be complete. Do you want to know how to contact that other website and get the details?

Comment: Well, it is connected actually, i just don't know how to get the field filled up and auto started using a jscript.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to auto-fill the details using your script. In that case, inspect the other website and see if the input fields have any id/name etc. You can then use JS APIs such getElementById / getElementsByName etc to get the exact input field. Post that you can set the data needed there.

Similarly you can get the button instance and invoke click on that. Let us know if you stuck at any specific point.

I don't think you will be able to inject your JS code directly on that website so that your code works for everyone(unless you find a security flaw)! You can just load that website, press F12(in Chrome) to open the debugger and then execute your scripts.